# SymFromAddr returns "The specified module could not be found."

Tags: c++, windows, debug-symbols

I'm trying to get symbols from addresses I got from my stack, but SymFromAddr keeps failing  with system error 126 (The specified module could not be found.)
I'm initializing the symboling thing with

```
SymInitialize(m_processHandle, NULL, TRUE);
```

(the last parameter == true ==> It loads the PDB automatically)

and I use SymFromAddr like this:

```
SYMBOL_INFO_PACKAGE sym = { sizeof(sym) };
sym.si.MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME; 
DWORD64 displacement = 0;
bool ok = SymFromAddr(m_processHandle, address, &displacement, &sym.si);
```

The code is in C++ on windows.
and the PDB FILE IS IN THE DIRECTORY OF THE EXE!
What am I doing wrong?
thanks :)

Comment: It should be sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) instead of sizeof(sym); not sure if that is causing the error, though.  You could use Process Monitor to see if it is looking in the expected place or not.

Comment: what? how can I use Process Monitor to do this? :)

Comment: You can verify if it is loading the .pdb file from the correct location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymFromAddr is a little bit capricious.

1. If any LoadLibrary occur between SymInitialize and SymFromAddr it may not work. If SymFromAddr you can perfom a SymInitialize again (hint: you can cache address to avoid a lot of SymInitialize which is a huge CPU consummer)
2. 64 bits implementation of SymFromAddr (ie. SymFromAddr64) works better
3. If code is not optimized it'll work better
4. VC9 generated pdb works better than older version.

You can find some idea in the following code
http://code.google.com/p/nprof/source/browse/0.11/Hook/StackWalker.cpp?r=281